# Problems with _init_()

Tags: python, class, object

I created this class to start a frame for each object, I'm doing a music player exercise.

```
class SoundPanel(Frame):
    def _init_(self, app, mixer, sound_file):
        Frame._init_(self, app)
        self.track = mixer.Sound(sound_file)
        self.track_playing = IntVar()
        track_button = Checkbutton(self, variable = self.track_playing,
                                         command = self.track_toogle,
                                         text = sound_file)
        track_button.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.volume = DoubleVar()
        self.volume.set(self.track.get_volume())
        volume_scale = Scale(self, variable = self.volume,
                                   from_ = 0.0,
                                   to = 1.0,
                                   resolution = 0.0,
                                   command = self.change_volume,
                                   label = "Volume",
                                   orient = HORIZONTAL )
        volume_scale.pack(side = RIGHT)

        def track_toggle(self):
            if self.track.playing.get() == 1:
              self.track.playing(loops = -1)

            else:
              self.track.stop()

        def change_volume(self, v):
          self.track.set_volume(self.volume.get())
```

when I try to create a object, is showing an error message, example:

```
panel = SoundPanel(app, mixer, "som1.wav")
panel.pack()

ERROR: 
panel = SoundPanel(app, mixer, "som1.wav")
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Already made my research here and tried to shorten/change the *init*() parameters.

Pls help :)

Comment: This is a common typo - see for example /questions/27649350/subclass-init-method-ignored-execution-jumps-straight-to-superclass-init . You need two underscores on each side.

Comment: You want to use the [`super()`](https://appdividend.com/2019/01/22/python-super-function-example-super-method-tutorial/) function. Instead of `Frame._init_(self, app)`, do: `super().__init__(app)`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good eyes. Didn't catch -- regardless, @OP, the above bug will also come up once you fix your `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a missunderstanding `__init__` with double underscores is the right usage not `_init_` not with single underscore on both sides.

You wrote like this;

```
def _init_(self, app, mixer, sound_file):
```

But it must be this;

```
def __init__(self, app, mixer, sound_file):
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name so it uses two underscores

```
def __init__(self, app, mixer, sound_file):
```

Comment: @CiaoAlves If any of the answers helped, feel free to mark the question as resolved https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers